# Почему не работает атрибут Compare?

Tags: c#, mvc, razor, атрибуты

Помогите разобраться, почему не работает тег. У меня есть класс регистрации:

```
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
            [DisplayName("Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [DisplayName("Пароль")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = "Пароли не совпадают")]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [DisplayName("Повторите пароль")]
            public string PasswordCompare { get; set; }
    }
```

В контроллере при регистрации вызывается этот метод:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var result = await model.Registration(_userManager, _signInManager);
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                        return View(ModelState);
                    }
                }
            return Redirect("/");
        }
```

Сам метод Registration:

```
   public static async Task<IdentityResult> Registration(this RegisterViewModel model, UserManager<UserViewModel> _userManager, SignInManager<UserViewModel> _signInManager)
        {
            UserViewModel user = new UserViewModel { Email = model.Email, UserName = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Пробовал разными способа черех хелпер Html, потому что, как я понимаю, ошибка не отображается только на клиенте и необходимо вывести ее в представление, но как ни экспериментировал не получилось:

```
<form class="decor" method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">
        <div class="form-left-decoration"></div>
        <div class="form-right-decoration"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="form-inner">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
            <h3 align="center">Регистрация</h3>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required asp-for="Email">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" required asp-for="Password">
            <div>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Повторите пароль" required asp-for="PasswordCompare">
                @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.PasswordCompare)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordCompare)
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Регистрация">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться где туплю

Comment: Я бы проводил валидацию подобного рода на фронте яваскриптом. Зачем серверу знать, смог юзер повторить пароль, или нет? Просто не отправлять форму, пока юзер не сможет повторить пароль. Меньше запросов на сервер - лучше.